# Не получается выгрузить pdf/jpg файлы из базы. (FireBird 2.5)

Tags: python, unicode, firebird, blob, ipython

Добрый день!
Использую Python 3.5 для решения этой задачи  + библиотеку fdb.
Скрипт:

```
import fdb
con = fdb.connect(
    host='host', database='database',
    user='IAKUZNETSOV', password='111111'
  )
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select DATA from ATTACHMENTS where OID = '6512165313'")
fileToSave= cur.fetchone()[0]
with open('c:\\python5.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fileToSave)
```

После попытки сохранения файла выдаётся ошибка:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                            

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6a7f8cf5e256> in <module>()
      6 cur = con.cursor()
      7 cur.execute("select FILE_DATA from DOC_ATTACHMENTS where OID = '620104150893'")
----> 8 fileToSave= cur.fetchone()[0]
      9 with open('c:\\python5.jpg', 'wb') as f:
     10     f.write(fileToSave)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in fetchone(self)
   3635         """
   3636         if self._ps:
-> 3637             return self._ps._fetchone()
   3638         else:
   3639             raise ProgrammingError("Cannot fetch from this cursor because"
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in _fetchone(self)
   3315                     ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(self._out_sqlda), XSQLDA_PTR))
   3316                 if self._last_fetch_status == 0:
-> 3317                     return self.__XSQLDA2Tuple(self._out_sqlda)
   3318                 elif self._last_fetch_status == self.RESULT_SET_EXHAUSTED:
   3319                     self._free_handle()
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in __XSQLDA2Tuple(self, xsqlda)
   2735                     if ((self.__charset or PYTHON_MAJOR_VER == 3)
   2736                         and sqlvar.sqlsubtype == 1):
-> 2737                         value = b2u(value,self.__python_charset)
   2738             elif vartype == SQL_ARRAY:
   2739                 value = []
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py in b2u(st, charset)
    432     "Decode to unicode if charset is defined. For conversion of result set data."
    433     if charset:
--> 434         return st.decode(charset)
    435     else:
    436         return st
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py in decode(self, input, errors)
     13 
     14     def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
---> 15         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
     16 
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 690: character maps `
```

Кодировка поля в базе: `Win-1251`, тип файла: `Blob`.

Comment: Какая может быть кодировка у блоба jpg? Это же просто массив байтов.

Comment: Почему у вас код пытается двоичные данные (такие как jpeg) декодировать в текст (Unicode)? Ошибка пытаться декодировать такие данные вне зависимости от кодировки—это не текст. Получается ли у вас записать/ прочитать blob вообще? К примеру `data = bytearray(range(0x100))` создайте минимальный, но полный пример, который пишет читает в простейшую таблицу эти данные.